# $(X,\tau)$ topological vector space (Hausdorff) is: locally compact $\iff$ of finite dimension.

Tags: vector-spaces, compactness

I am trying to show that in any finite dimensional normed vector space, the unit ball is compact.
To do this, I first proved that:

$(X,|\cdot |_X)$ normed vector space is: locally compact $\iff$ the ball $\widetilde{B}(0;1)=\{x\in X \;| \;|x|_X\leq 1\}$ is compact.

having done this, I would need to prove that:

$(X,\tau)$ topological vector space (Hausdorff) is: locally compact $\iff$ of finite dimension.

To do this, I found this document: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/ where "Theorem 1" represents the implication "$\Rightarrow$" of the statement that I want to prove.
There are some steps that unfortunately I have not been able to understand, in particular the demonstration begins with:

*Let V be a locally compact Hausdorff space, thus there exists a compact neighbourhood K of the origin. Then the dilate $\frac{1}{2}K$ is also a neighbourhood of the origin, and so by compactness K can be covered by finitely many translates of $\frac{1}{2}K$...*

I don't understand why we are sure that $\frac{1}{2}K=\{\frac{k}{2}\}_{k\in K}$ is a neighborhood of the origin. To affirm this we should be certain that in the topology $ \tau $ there is also an open whose closure is equal to $\frac{1}{2}K$.

No?

Comment: This is certainly overkill for what you say you want to prove in the first sentence. Any finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual topology and the isomorphism maps the unit ball to a closed and bounded set. Then just apply Heine-Borel to that set.

Comment: $x \to \frac x 2$ is a homeomorphism. So it preserves compact neighborhoods.

Comment: @RhysSteele If I have a finite-dimensional vector space $X$, then I can found a linear bijective mapping between $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, ok.
Why did you say "with its usual topology"? I have a generic norm on $X$, so a generic metric, so a generic topology on it. I realize that I'm missing some simple key steps, but I don't see it and I ask you to help me understand please.

Comment: In the context of e.g. normed vector spaces an isomorphism has the stronger property that it is a bijective linear homeomorphism (i.e. both it and its inverse are continuous). This is where the the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ enters the picture. My comment shows that the unit ball on $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact by Heine-Borel and hence so is the unit ball (homeomorphisms preserve compactness).

Comment: The reasoning is very clear, thanks. What I miss is the fact that any linear function between normed vector spaces in which the domain has finite dimension is continuous. I found this proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#If_a_linear_map_is_finite_dimensional.2C_the_linear_map_is_continuous .

It uses equivalence of norms. But the equivalence of norms is proved thanks to the fact that the unit ball is compact (https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf). It looks like a loop.

Comment: That's just because the different authors choose to prove those facts in different orders. Try checking any functional analysis textbook that proves both facts and you'll get a non-circular presentation ("Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" by Kreyszig, "Linear functional analysis" by Rynne and Youngson or basically any other textbook will do this). Also Theorem 4.2 in [these notes](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/42040) proves that the isomorphism in question is a homeomorphism directly in a way that doesn't assume any result you can't use here.